# MSIX installer project - which files to commit to repository?

Tags: version-control, msix

I've created an MSIX installation project for my WinForm app, and now I'd like to commit it to my repository (git). I can't figure out which files are essential and which are now.

I assume I should commit `.wapproj`, `<my public key>.pfx`, `Package.appxmanifest` and the whole Images folder.
I know I shouldn't commit `.user` or `obj` files.
What do I do about `bin` and `BundleArtifacts` folders and why?

Comment: Did you create it with the Desktop Packaging Project in VS? That should automatically know how to add itself safely to Git.

Comment: I did. I'm not sure how the installation project will know anything, do you mean it will show in the Team Explorer? I'm not using git from within VS normally, so maybe I'm missing something, but all I see in the Team Explorer is all the new files that were created for the installer project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at a repo on such as [this Build demo](https://github.com/ptorr-msft/Build2020WvdMigrationDemo/tree/master/src/WvdMigration) to see which files should be included in source control. Essentially it is the `.wapproj` and the `.appxmanifest` files, plus the images (and then of course the actual app source code).

You shouldn't include the `.pfx` file since that also includes the private key used to sign the package.